# Empirical tight-binding sp$^3$s* band structure of semiconductors

Tags: semiconductor-physics, tight-binding, spin-orbit

I'm simulating on code the tight-binding sp<sup>3</sup>s* bandstructure of certain semiconductors, such as GaAs, AlP, InP, ZnSe, etc. with spin-orbit coupling at a temperature of $T = 0$ K but I'm having trouble at finding the corresponding spin-orbit splitting parameters.

For example, I've found in this article by *Vogl et al* ([A Semi-Empricial Tight-Binding Theory of the Electronic Structure of Semiconductors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022369783900641?via%3Dihub)) the following relation of spin-orbit parameters:

[image: Electronic structure of semiconductors [Extracted from Vogl et al]]

But the temperature is not said anywhere in that article. In fact, the tight binding parameters without spin-orbit coupling depend a lot on the temperature. At this point, the only information that is certain for me is the following:

1. At $T = 300$ K the desired parameters appear in this article by *Klimeck et al*: [sp3s* Tight-binding parameters for transport simulations in compound semiconductors](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0749603600908620?via%3Dihub)
2. At $T = 0$ K I know from chapter 5 of Supriyo Datta's *[Quantum Transport, Atom to Transistor](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-transport/E96BE74AACD59A03A7D6A7F7DACDFB71)* that the spin-orbit parameters, only for GaAs are $\Delta_a = 0.37$ eV for arsenic and $\Delta_c = 0.013$ eV for gallium. The other semiconductors are not mentioned.

Based on what I've said above, do you know where I could find the spin-orbit splitting parameters for the semiconductors on Table 4 at $T = 0$ K, and if it were possible their dependance with the temperature? Any references will be appreciated.

Thank you very much!